# How to make a circuit-breaker in Istio?

Tags: proxy, istio, envoyproxy, servicemesh

I am trying to configure a circuit breaker in Istio. This is the yaml.

```
trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      http:
        http1MaxPendingRequests: 1
        maxRequestsPerConnection: 1
      tcp:
        maxConnections: 1
    outlierDetection:
      baseEjectionTime: 1m
      consecutive5xxErrors: 1
      interval: 1s
```

I have a list of thread groups in JMeter that will be continously hitting the service associated with the above circuit breaker. Upon receiving an error response, it should be making the service unavailable for 1 minute. But, that is not happenning.

Am I misunderstanding how it works? Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Did you enable istio sidecar injection? How many pods are there in the target service? Have you tried the example from the [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/circuit-breaking/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing between `outlier detection` and `circuit breaker based on connectionPool settings`.

The settings you are applying in the connectionPool will configure a circuit breaker where if any of the limits are breached then circuit will be tripped and new requests will get an immideate 503 response from istio proxy. As in the new requests will not be sent to the application.
However, the proxy will accept new requests as soon as it can (when limits are not breached by accepting the new request).
There is no such thing as circuit breaking for 1 minute in this context.

Outlier detection is different. This works by tripping a particular error prone POD from the load balancing pool.
Suppose, you have 4 replica pods running for your deployment. And let us say one of the PODs is giving 5xx error (`The 503 errors sent by proxy, like in the connection pool breach case, are not counted here.` This count is of your application errors). In this case istio will wait for consecutive5xxErrors (1 in your case) and once this is breached it will remove that pod from load balancing for the baseEjectionTime for the first time.
That is, it will wait for `baseEjectionTime` (1m in your case). Till then no new request will be sent to the error proned POD. After 1 minute it will add the POD again to the load balancing pool. But if again this POD breaches the consecutive5xxErrors (1 in your case) then istio will remove it from the load balancing for `2xbaseEjectionTime` which would be 2 minutes in your case.
This will keep going until your POD is back giving non 5XX errors.

Comment: I don't want to break the circuit on the basis of limit. I want to break it on the basis of 5xx errors. Is it possible to do with connectionPool settings? If not, what can be the solution?

Comment: you are doing with 5xx errors, but at pod level, not at service level. If you have one pod then you will see the behaviour immidiately, otherwise all pods will be tried before they are removed from LB. If you set maxEjectionPercent to 100, then all pods can be removed and you will get service level 503 error.

Answer (score 1):

With the information you provided I think the problem might the parameter `maxEjectionPercent` not being set in your `DestiationRule`:

> maxEjectionPercent - Maximum % of hosts in the load balancing pool for the upstream service that can be ejected. Defaults to 10%.

Since it default to 10% this means that only 10% of you deployment will ejected by circuit breaker. For testing purposes you might try to set this to 100%, similar the [documentiation to demonstrate this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/circuit-breaking/):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  host: httpbin
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      tcp:
        maxConnections: 1
      http:
        http1MaxPendingRequests: 1
        maxRequestsPerConnection: 1
    outlierDetection:
      consecutive5xxErrors: 1
      interval: 1s
      baseEjectionTime: 3m
      maxEjectionPercent: 100
```

I have tested the example in the docs and it works fine for me.

Another possible issue might be sidecar injection. Please verify that your pod actually has one (you should see 2 out 2 containers ready inside the pod):

```
 ~  kgp                                                                                                                                    ✔  cluster-1 ⎈
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
fortio-deploy-576dbdfbc4-9crcf   2/2     Running   0          46m
httpbin-74fb669cc6-mg9rh         2/2     Running   0          48m
```